# sql Req didnt update the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem is my update req did not update my base

but I have no idea where is my probleme

```
function updatePartenaire($array=array()){
  $db =dataBase();
  echo " in function ";

  $req= "UPDATE parteners SET typeAction ='".$array['type']."' WHERE partener_id ='".$array['id']."'";
  echo "$req";
  $prepare=mysqli_prepare($db,$req);
  echo "end prepare \r\n";
  mysqli_stmt_execute($prepare);
  echo "end execute \r\n";
  echo "end function";
}
```

[Reponses I catch form the network minitor]

```
Loading Page ajaxReq.Controller.php Page load sucesse 
 page value : partenaire
 Load Page : partenaire 
 Catche value action : updatefile find  
 type Action : update 
 Catche value type : 4 Catche value id : 75array(2) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "75"
}

function existe
 start function updatePartenaire  in function UPDATE parteners SET typeAction ='4' WHERE partener_id ='75'end prepare 
end execute 
end function
```

I have commenter everywhere for look where it stops, but it just runs to the end without any error

I have copied the req and execute in the database console .
no error and my database is updated (same request) and I have doublechecked the database connection config is right

[image: when i lance the req in the phpmyadmin console]

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need isolate the problem and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a clear explanation of what isn't working with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/).

Comment: Check for  [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) after your execute. At this point, you're just blindly assuming that everything works.

Comment: please be specific to the problem first check properly what is the error... query not working or AJAX or PHP error...

Comment: maybe u dont have `partener_id ='75'` in your database, this is my assumption because your debugging is printing each and everything till the end. as u mentioned in `Response`

Comment: OR run this query `UPDATE parteners SET typeAction ='4' WHERE partener_id ='75'` directly to PHPMYadmin , you will get the answer. , second why are u not using bind param here?

Comment: @devpro this what i did and no msg error

Comment: run this `UPDATE parteners SET typeAction ='4' WHERE partener_id ='75'` in phpmyadmin and check is it working or not

Comment: @devpro i have upload the pic

Comment: `if($prepare){mysqli_stmt_execute($prepare);}else{printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($prepare));}` check errors

Comment: @devpro well it return "Error: ." ,i just delet all  reset to 0 and with classic pdo $db ->prepare($req); and it work ..

Comment: thats good ....

Comment: Bit off topic : how about tooling up and learning to use a proper IDE ?  you would maximize the use of your time, and hardly ever have to post one like this here. Also, you are likely to make more mistakes in you `debug` echo statements than any other statement.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg i'm agree with you, use the ```echo``` to debug could make more mistakes but this the most simple way to debug . no :/?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change $array['type'] to ? and $array['id'] to ? and use [statement bind](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to bind values as this is what prepare is supposed to do.